# SQL Server - Need to check spelling errors in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Looking for a quick help.
In Sql, one of the table has a column(ntext). I need to find the count of spelling mistakes in the field. Association of MS Word dictionary would be great, however, can work with any other dictionary as well.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be to read the text fields and pass them through a spellcheck library such as PyEnchant to count how many misspelt words there are (see [Python: check whether a word is spelled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500752/python-check-whether-a-word-is-spelled-correctly), https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html)

Otherwise, if you want to use MS Word spellcheck specifically, you can find some ideas here: [Using MS Office's Spellchecking feature with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975886/using-ms-offices-spellchecking-feature-with-c-sharp) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Micah, however, I am looking for coding in sql.

For example one of my column value is - 'Liives' instead of 'Lives' then I should get 1 in column name 'Error_Count'

And if anyone can share the code for this then it would be a great help.

Thanks,
Victor